# Create a trigger on Delete customer that displays a message, "Customer Number 217 is deleted"

Tags: sql, oracle, ssh

This is a homework problem.
The customer table consists of:  customer_num,customer_name,street,city,state,postal_code,balance,credit_limit,rep_num.  This table would be linked to the rep table via rep_num, and the orders table via customer_num.  I have inserted a row into the customer table, just so I will not be deleting actual data, so my code to insert the row is:

```
insert into customer
    values('217','Big Bird','123 Sesame
    Street','Pittsburgh','PA','15301',1.00,100.00,'15');
```

I then set the server output on:

```
set serveroutput on;
```

Here is my code that is giving me the rejection of, "Warning:  Trigger created with compilation errors.":

```
create or replace trigger print_customer_deleted
after delete on customer for each row
begin
delete customer_num
set on customer = on.customer - new.customer_num
where customer_num = :new.customer_num;

dbms_output.put_line('Customer number '||customer_num||
                    ' is deleted');
end;
/
```

Also, would this be how my trigger would be executed? :

```
accept item_num prompt 'Enter customer number to be deleted: ';

execute print_customer_deleted('&customer_num');
```

Comment: The syntax of your delete statement inside the trigger doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The code in a trigger is executed in addition to the triggering event, so it should not attempt to trigger another delete of the same table you are already deleting from, as that will call the trigger again in an endless cascade, eventually creating a black hole that will consume our world. Also, check the docs for [`delete` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8005.htm). There's no `set on` clause, whatever that was intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a TEST table based on Scott's DEPT. Trigger (after delete on DEPT) deletes a row from TEST and displays a message.

```
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> create table test as select * From dept;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ad_dept
  2    after delete on dept
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    delete from test
  6      where deptno = :old.deptno;
  7
  8    dbms_output.put_line('Department #' || :old.deptno ||' is deleted');
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's see how it works:

```
SQL> delete from dept where deptno = 30;
Department #30 is deleted

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> select * From test;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Seems to be OK - department #30 has been deleted from both tables & the message was displayed.

Apply it to your situation (I don't have your tables, and you didn't provide test case).

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you so much. @Littlefoot

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it answers your question.